# Symfony: How to handle date field in a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, view, twig

I'm using Symfony 2.6...

I have some questions about date fields in a form!

1) If i use  `{{ form_row (form.data) }}` on a date field in twig file the system renders it as a date in **US/EN** style (month day year)... can i obtain it in **EU/IT** style?

3) How **form_row** works with date?

4) Is it possible to have the **month** in italian? and possibly in long form? (my clients are old italian people)

Comment: You can define your own Date format using format option of the DateType.

Comment: A better choice IMHO would be usage of a JS Date Picker to avoid any wrongly entered dates.

Comment: I've tried... but it doesn't work. **Frankbeen** answer is ok!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that php's **intl** extension is enabled on your webserver and that you changed **en** to **it** in app/config/config.yml at the **default_locale:** option and the order of year/month/day should change to the italian standard.

An other solution is to change te format for that single field. You can [read it in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format).

Answer (score 0):

1)
Probably you get that format because it is defined in a default form style. The easiest way is to override that style in the twig you are going to use using form `customisation(http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).`

If you define `{% form_theme form_self %}` in the beginning of the twig block, you can override your default form type which is defined in `form_div_layout.html.twig(find the link to the code inside the page cited above)`.
Inside that code, the rendering part of the date will be around `{%- block date_widget -%},` so if you can redefine this block in your twig, probably that will change the default behavior of

```
{{form_row (form.data)}}
```

3)
form_row returns a set of field's label, errors and widget(http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html).
In the case of date, it will usually return label and date string in a format defined in your form style.

4)How would you exactly like to express the month? If it can be separate and only have to be rendered in a confirmation screen, maybe you could get the value inside the controller when you submit the form then get the form value, then you can return it in a twig again.

```
{% if month == '1' }Gennaio{% endif %}
{% if month == '2' }Febbraio{% endif %}
```

:
:
:

This is very naive, but I think at least for input, it is not so difficult to enter a month by digits. As suggested in the comments above, DatePicker would do that job in most cases.

Comment: Yes is a naive solution. It's a bit log to code to log form and decode back to original format before insert a record in a DB... it's complicated to use a iterator also... I've found a satisfying answer by **Frankbeen**, i will be happy with italian style date with a 3 char month... unless my clients...